# Showing $x^4-24x^2+4$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification, irreducible-polynomials

> I want to show that  $x^4-24x^2+4$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I have tried Eisenstein's criterion using $p=2$ and substituting $x+1$ and $x-1$ but it won't work. Then what I tried was using the rational root test. I got as my possible rational roots $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm4$. But each one does not work. From here I can consider $x^4-24x^2+4$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. So suppose that  $x^4-24x^2+4$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. Then  $$x^4-24x^2+4= (x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)=x^4+(a+c)x^3+(b+ac+d)x^2+(bc+ad)x+bd.$$ By matching up the coefficients we get $$a+c=0$$ $$b+ac+d=-24$$ $$bd=4$$ $$bc+ad=0$$

Then we see $a+c=0\implies a=-c$. Then $$bc+ad=0\implies bc-cd=0 \implies bc=cd\implies b=d.$$ Since $bd=4$ then $b^2=4\implies b=\pm 2$ and $d=\pm 2$. We get two cases: $b=d=2$ and $b=d=-2$. In the first case $b=d=2$ we get $b+ac+d=-24\implies 4-c^2=-24\implies c^2=28$ (I substituted $a=-c$ into $b+ac+d=-24$), a contradiction since $c$ is an integer. Similarly in the case $b=d=-2$ we have $ b+ac+d=-24\implies -4-c^2=-24\implies c^2=20$. Again a contradiction. Would this be correct?

Comment: could you please explain your statement "From here I can consider $x^4−24x^2+4$ over Z. "

Comment: It's biquadratic, so you can find its zeros. This opens up the option of writing down all the possible quadratic factors over $\Bbb{C}$ and checking whether the coefficients are rational or not.

Comment: So what I showed would be incorrect then?

Comment: @user60887 why do you think you are wrong?

Comment: Oh maybe an arithmetic error. But the theorem I used was "A polynomial with integer coefficients that can be factored into polynomials with rational coefficients can also be factored into polynomials of the same degree with integer coefficients".

Comment: @user60887 yes.. I was just making sure if you are familiar with that... your solution looks fine to me.. let some one confirm it....

Comment: So what I did only worked because im working with a polynomial with degree 4? If it was degree 3 then it be wrong?

Comment: No.. No.. who said that?? It will still be correct...

Comment: Oh ok. I read it in your answer. I thought you meant what I did.

Comment: No No.. I meant what i did :P

Comment: The solution looks quite good to me actually. You ignored the possibility $c=0$ when you deduced $b=d$, but that is easy to eliminate (see Praphulla's answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^4-24x^2+4=t^2-24t+4=0 \Rightarrow t=12\pm 2\sqrt{35}\Rightarrow x^2-(12\pm 2\sqrt{35})=0$

I was a bit excited (Not careless ) and concluded that given polynomial is irreducible.

But It is not proper to conlcude at this stage but rather find all other roots and then check for possible combinations.

$x^2=12+2\sqrt{35}\Rightarrow x= \pm(\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{5})$ and $x^2=12-2\sqrt{35}\Rightarrow x= \pm(\sqrt{7}-\sqrt{5})$

Now we have all roots of $x^4-24x^2+4$ as $\pm(\sqrt{7}\pm\sqrt{5})$

It would be now your duty to check if :

$(x-a)(x-b)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ where $a,b \in \{\pm(\sqrt{7}\pm\sqrt{5})\}$ and $a\neq b$.

So, now i will  leave this to you conclude this polynomial is irreducible/not in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Danger : This worked out only because you have only $x^4$ and $x^2$ and no $x^3$.

This is done under experts supervision(It is not me). please do not repeat this at home. :D

Comment: Why does this prove that it is not irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$? The numbers $12\pm2\sqrt{35}$ are not rational. My suggestion meant that you find the four zeros $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$, and then check whether any of the quadratic factors $(x-x_1)(x-x_j)$, $j=2,3,4,$ in $\Bbb{C}[x]$ has integer coefficients. As you correctly stated in the comments, if the original quartic has factors with rational coefficients it also should have factors with integer coefficients.

Comment: What's the point of this answer?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Oh yes... I should have been more careful.... I would immediately edit this... with in 2 minutes

Comment: @user : The point of the answer is as it is explained by Mr. Jyrki Lahtonen.. there was some slight misunderstanding...

Comment: By the reasoning of this answer, $x^4+x^2+1$ would also be irreducible over$~\Bbb Q$, but it isn't.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen : I have edited the answer... could you please review my answer..

Comment: Yes, if you actually check all $\binom42=6$ products $(x-a)(x-b)$ to be non-rational polynomials, this argument suffices. It is in fact easy to see that the coefficient of $x$ will only be rational if $a=-b$, in which case the constant term $-a^2=-12-2\sqrt{35}$ is non-rational.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen : Yes yes... that idea of $a=-b$ makes so much sense than that of my idea of checking everything:) Thank you..

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : I would be thankful if you can see this and confirm if i am missing something..

Comment: +1: Nice observation of realizing that the roots are $\pm\sqrt7\pm\sqrt5$ (I didn't foresee that).

Comment: Thank You Sir. But i was expecting the solution to be much simpler than this...

Comment: A variation of the ending: Knowing that the roots are so pretty, you can see that the polynomial is irreducible by noticing these roots are all the Galois conjugates of $\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{5}$ when we consider the Galois extension ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7}) / {\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: @PabloRotondo : I doubt that I can not say that at this point as the OP may not be familiar with what a Galois extension is... It is a nice answer though :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that you have a monic even polynomial (it is invariant under substituting $x:=-x$) of degree $4$. You can therefore consider two cases for potential factors of the polynomial: factors that are themselves even, and factors that are not; the latter come in pairs whose members are interchanged by the substitution $x:=-x$ (which flips the signs of the odd degree terms). Any non-trivial even proper factor must be of the form $x^2-r$ where $r$ satisfies $r^2-24r+4=0$, but the discriminant $560=16*35$ of that polynomial is not a square in$~\Bbb Z$, so there are no such integer$~r$ (this is the case that the initial answer by Praphulla Koushik checked).

So you are left to check a potential factorisation $x^4-24x^2+4=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2-ax+b)$. This gives equations $b^2=4$ (from the constant term) and $a^2=2b+24$ (from the coefficient of $x^2$). It is easily checked that there are no solutions $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ to this system (neither $24+4$ nor $24-4$ is a square).